# 3 Tier application with singleton Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

I am Just creating a 3 Tier WinForm Application with following pattern.

-- MY BASE CLASS : DAL Class

```
public class Domain
{

    public string CommandName = string.Empty;
    public List<Object> Parameters = new List<Object>();

    public void Save()   
    {
        List<Object> Params = this.SaveEntity();
        this.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandName, Params.ToArray());
    }

    public void Delete() 
    {
        List<Object> Params = this.DeleteEntity();
        this.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandName, Params.ToArray());
    }

    public void Update() 
    {
        List<Object> Params = this.UpdateEntity();
        this.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandName, Params.ToArray());
    }

    protected virtual List<Object> SaveEntity()
    {
        return null;
    }
    protected virtual List<Object> UpdateEntity()
    { 
        return null;
    }
    protected virtual List<Object> DeleteEntity()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string SqlText, params object[] Params)
    {
        /*
         * Code block for executing Sql
         */
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**My Business Layer Class which is going to inherit DLL Class**

-- MY Children CLASS : BLL CLASS

```
public class Person : Domain
{
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string number
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override List<object> SaveEntity()
    {
        this.Parameters.Add(name);
        this.Parameters.Add(number);
        return this.Parameters;
    }
}
```

-- USE
**This is way to use my Base Class**

```
void Main()
{
    Person p = new Person();
    p.name = "Vijay";
    p.number = "23";
    p.Save();
}
```

**Questions**

- Is this the right architecture I am following and Is there any chance to create the base class as Singleton?
- Is there any other batter architecture?
- Is there any pattern I can follow to extend my functionality?

Kindly suggest.

Comment: So the his problem is that he is missing the forth one ?

Comment: 3 tire architecture... sounds like a [trike](http://static.blogo.it/motoblog/special-trike-americani/special_trike_01.jpg) :)

Comment: a candidate for code review or programmers ?

Comment: @Seki I approve your edit, but you are ruining the joke :-)

Comment: @Steve: I am very sorry for that :)  (There is still the changes history though)

Comment: Is there missing something? give me idea and your thought

Comment: Check the translation of `Tire` in your native language. :-)

Comment: don't look into translation, look into problem may be it can help someone.

Comment: My friend, there's so many problem in the code you propose, I wouldn't know where to start...

Comment: Just start, I will try to understand as my application will run in multi-user environment?

Comment: If you would not tell me then how can I understand the problem.

Comment: Please if you know something then tell me. :(

Comment: One main thing, about above mentioned approach... I am using SQL stored procedure very heavily.

Comment: Please give me advice, in your Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see. I would try to give my input. 
What I see here you are trying to do is ORM. So please change the name of base class from Domain to something else

**Is this the right architecture I am following and Is there any chance to create the base class as Singleton?**

Why do you need you base class as singleton. You would be inheriting your base class and you would create instances of child classes. Never ever you would be creating a instance of base itself.(99% times :) )

**Is there any other batter architecture?**

Understand this. To do a certain thing, there could be multiple ways. Its just the matter of fact, which one suits you the most.

**Is there any pattern I can follow to extend my functionality?**

Always remember the SOLID principles which gives you loose coupling and allow easy extensibility.

[SOLID](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/biswapinky/solid-principles-of-oops/)

There are couple of changes that I would suggest. Instead of a base class, start with Interface and then inherit it to make an abstract class.

Also make sure your base class can do all the CRUD functionality. I do not see a retrieval functionality here. How are you planning to do it? Probably you need a repository class that returns all the entity of your application. So when you need person, you would just go on ask the repository to return all the Person.

All said and done, there are lots of ORM tool, that does this kind of functionality and saves developer time. Its better to learn those technologies. For example LINQ - SQL.

Comment: For First Point... I want the same as singleton not because of child class, but because of other entity. As If you look into my code, I mentioned functions related to Executing sql procedure and text (ExecuteNonQuery/ExecuteDataTable/ExecuteScaler/ExecuteDataSet). So all other entity which is not inheriting Base class can have access to data layer as, In presentation some time we need to execute some custom code. For data retrial I always use datatable and populate the UI with that table. I never use class object to populate my UI.

Comment: I not much of fan of ORM, as they always need column mapping. And also If we want to do some custom operation on Database then It will more difficult in ORM. The same can be easily implementing using sql stored procedure.

Comment: I think then you should separate your sql helper functions in to another class and make it static. Its one of the principle of SOLID that I was talking about(single responsibility). And for retrival you use DataTable, but what I wanted to ask was where are you calling this code. You see your Create, Update and Delete functionality resides with in the object only. Where should retrival part lie ? Thats why I suggeseted you create a common class called as repository which then return all the entities of your application. Like Repository.GetPerson()

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the right architecture I am following

There is no architecture which is optimal for any problem without context. That said, there *are* things that you can do to make your life more difficult. Singleton is not your problem in your implementation.

> Is there any other batter architecture?

Probably, yes. Just glimpsing at the code, I see quite a lot of stuff that is going to hurt you in the near and not so near future.

First, a piece of advice: **get the basics right**, don't run before you can walk. This may be the cause for the downvotes.

Some random issues:

- You are talking about 3-Tier architecture, but there are technically no tiers there, not even layers. `Person` doesn't look like business logic to me: if I understood correctly, it also must supply the string for the commands to execute, so it has to know SQL.
- Empty virtual methods should be abstract. If you want to be able to execute arbitrary SQL move this outside the class
- As @Anand pointed out, there are no methods to query
- CommandName and Parameters are exposed as fields instead of properties
- CommandName is not a Name, Domain doesn't look like a fitting name for that class
- It looks like an awkward solution to a well-known problem (ORM). You say that you want to be able to execute custom SQL but any decent ORM should be able to let you do that.

Suggested reads: [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) for the basic stuff and [Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X) for some clarity on the architectural patterns you could need.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Anand, I removed all SQL related functions from my base class and put them all in another class, `Sql`.

Following that, I made the `Sql` class into a singleton. And I stored the `Sql` instance in `BaseDAL` so it can be accessible in all DAL class.

My code looks something like this

```
public class BaseDAL
{
    // Singleton Instance
    protected Sql _dal = Sql.Instance;

    public string CommandName = string.Empty;
    public List<Object> Parameters = new List<Object>();

    public void Save()   
    {
        List<Object> Params = this.SaveEntity();
        _dal.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandName, Params.ToArray());
    }

    public void Delete() 
    {
        List<Object> Params = this.DeleteEntity();
        _dal.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandName, Params.ToArray());
    }

    public void Update() 
    {
        List<Object> Params = this.UpdateEntity();
        _dal.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandName, Params.ToArray());
    }

    protected virtual List<Object> SaveEntity()
    {
        return null;
    }
    protected virtual List<Object> UpdateEntity()
    { 
        return null;
    }
    protected virtual List<Object> DeleteEntity()
    {
        return null;
    }

   // Other functions, like DataTable and DataSet querying
}
```

And the new SQL class is

```
public class Sql
{

    // All other functions are also present in this class for DataTable DataSet and many other 
    // So this class is more then enough for me.
    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string SqlText, params object[] Params)
    {
        // Code block for executing SQL
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`CommandName` and `Parameters` are exposed as fields instead of properties. In the original solution, they were properties. Also, I have a method in BaseDAL to query data so to help with implementing the `Person` class.